# open a particular file by default in an already installed 3rd party app?

Tags: android, pdf, android-intent, launch

Is it possible to open a particular PDF file in a 3rd party PDF reader (e.g. Adobe reader) by default on start up of the application by passing an intent from my android app?

Is this possible? How should the intent be passed to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it's possible.

You will need to launch an `Intent` with `ACTION_VIEW` with corresponding mime type, and the document should be opened in a 3d party pdf reader, if any available on your phone.

```
String path="...../file.pdf";
Intent intent=new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(new File(path)), "application/pdf");
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: i used this for opening pdf and worked like a charm but when i tried opening a .xls using this      'intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(new File(path)), "application/xls");' the application force closes.... how can i fix this

Comment: found it :)   " intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(new File(path)), "application/vnd.ms-excel"); "